# produce leading 0 in the minutes field

Tags: t-sql

This snippet:

```
select Datename(hh,DATEADD(HH, -5, [time])) + ':' + Datename(mi,[time])....
```

will produce:

```
11:4
```

But i need the leading '0' in front of the '4'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad the minutes with leading zeros, and then take the right two characters:

```
SELECT Datename(hh,DATEADD(HH, -5, [time])) + ':' + 
    right('00' + Datename(mi,[time]), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @hoje datetime = getdate()
select @hoje,format(@hoje,'HH') +':' + format(@hoje,'mm')